# Whether Lasseter is good at storytelling and in the use of technology or not?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

A sentence from Steve Jobs，

> “Lasseter's *shorts* were really breathtaking both in storytelling and in the use of technology. I tried so hard to get him to Disney, but he was loyal to Steve Jobs and Pixar”

Shorts means limitations? But the rest of the sentence make me confused that whether Lasseter is good at storytelling and in the use of technology, or not?

Comment: @Max already provided a good answer to your question.  I just wanted to clarify that the word meaning limitations you were probably thinking of is 'shortcomings'.  You were close.

Comment: "Short" means "short film", like this one, the first from Pixar [Luxo Jr. (1986)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4NPQ8mfKU0)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with the jargon, but I think it's an abbreviation of *short film*, specifically an *animated short film*. From Wikipedia

> A [**short film**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_film), is a cinema format, denoting any film not long enough to be considered a feature film. Although no consensus exists as to where that boundary is drawn, the Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences defines a short film as "an original motion picture that has a running time of 40 minutes or less, including all credits". The term featurette originally applied to a film longer than a short subject, but shorter than a standard feature film.
>
> The increasingly rare term "short subject" means approximately the same thing. It is an industry term which carries more of an assumption that the film is shown as part of a presentation along with a feature film. ***Short*** is an abbreviation for either term.

His shorts showed that he was good at both storytelling and technology.

Comment: Oh,,,,,that make sense! Sorry for my misunderstanding.